# Android Fragments: fragments inside a Frame or other layouts?

Tags: java, android, performance, fragment, android-framelayout

I am creating an Android app right now and I have a Frame which shell contain fragments. Till now all works fine, but I have come to a question which I cannot fully understand.

I have a Frame which is the entire screen (FrameLayout - should i use a FrameLayout as the main Frame?) and inside this Frame there are fragments that change, depending on the users interaction. These fragments are in the .xml files FrameLayouts. I am wondering now whether they can or should be FrameLayouts or fragments... I created a Google Maps frgment which is a fragment ideed and that made me thinking.

So my question ist: Does it make a difference or has it any impact on the perfomance or can I simple use whatever serves it's purpose?

To show what I mean, here are some code samples:
(Inside the FrameLayout inside the Framelayout are all fragments put)

MainFrame (activity_main.xml):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "@dimen/bottom_Main_Tabs">
        </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "@dimen/bottom_Main_Tabs"
        android:layout_gravity = "bottom"
        android:background="@color/grey2"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id = "@+id/bottomButton_home"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_width = "0dp"
            android:layout_weight = "1.0"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight = "2dp"
            android:background = "@drawable/ic_home_white"
            android:onClick = "openHome"
            />

        [...]

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/TopBar"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "@dimen/top_Bar_Hight"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/grey_transparentBy50"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id= "@+id/TopBarLogo"
            android:layout_width = "@dimen/top_Bar_Hight"
            android:layout_height = "@dimen/top_Bar_Hight"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />

         [...]

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

One Fragment (FrameLayout:)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context="com.domain.app.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:text="Home" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Another Frament (fragment)

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context="com.domain.app.MapsActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          tools:layout = "@layout/activity_main"
    />
```

Is too hae problems with the GoogleMaps implementation but I have not spent enough time on it yet to ask about help here.

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: could you paste xml files content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attaching fragments in xml like GoogleMapFragment or by using FrameLayout(or any other ViewGroup like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) in xml. Both ways are same. It is more likely creating a textview programmatically (i.e. in Java) or defining it in xml.

Using fragment in Java:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and in xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here R.id.fragment_container is id of your Frame Layout.

Using fragment in XML:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.ExampleFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In case of Fragment in XML your fragment will be defined by `<fragment/>`  xml tag and on the other side when we are using fragments programmatically, your FrameLayout will work as a container for your fragment.

Conclusion: Using FrameLayout will increase a hierarchy by one but it will not effect your performance very much.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

> The android:name attribute in the  specifies the Fragment
>   class to instantiate in the layout. When the system creates this
>   activity layout, it instantiates each fragment specified in the layout
>   and calls the onCreateView() method for each one, to retrieve each
>   fragment's layout. The system inserts the View returned by the
>   fragment directly in place of the  element.

Comment: ok, I have read your answer several times but I cannot completly follow. Could you be a bit more detailed? I am very new to android...

Comment: @JRsz:The difference between using FrameLayout and fragment in xml for fragments is your question right?

Comment: @JRsz: I have updated my answer, i think now it is more understandable.

Comment: yes thank you! I thnink I will use the FrameLayout version :)